# R glm table function with predict output

Tags: r, glm

I am curious why this simple code doesn't work for me:

```
wine$taste <- ifelse(wine$quality < 6, 0, 1)
wine$taste <- as.factor(wine$taste)

set.seed(123)
samp <- sample(nrow(wine), 0.6 * nrow(wine))
train <- wine[samp, ]
test <- wine[-samp, ]

mylogit <- glm(taste ~ pH+alcohol+density, data = train, family = binomial)

pred = predict(mylogit, newdata=test)
accuracy <- table(pred, test[,"taste"])
```

table gives the error:

> Error in table(pred, test[, "taste"]) :
>     alle Argumente müssen die selbe Länge haben

Is there a problem with factors and numeric values? All values are numeric but the variable taste...

What arguments does the table function take?

Answer (score 0):

Are these data available in a package, so that I could recreate the analysis? Regardless, I think that it is in the way you specified the test set classes. You said `test[,"taste"]`, which *might* return an object with length of `1` (which is why you get the error saying they must be of the same length), where the one element is `$taste`, which in turn contains the class labels you are looking for.

What you need to do is tell it that you want that `$taste` element directly. Try:

```
table(pred, test$taste)
```

It could also be that you need to specify what part of the predicted values you want. Different functions return different types of predicted objects. What does `str(predict)` return? You might find that it returns classes, probabilities, lots of things. You might have to specify that you want the class, not the probabilities.

Comment: Ok this helpe with test$tasrte. I dont know why

Comment: Why is test[,"taste"] and test$taste not the same?

Comment: Someone else might know why, but in my experience, *sometimes* specifying only part of a data frame like that will give return to you: "Here is a data frame, with one variable," where that variable must be explicitly called using `$`. Try seeing what `length(pred)` and `length(test[,"taste"])` are.